# HTML scrolling div layout problem

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to design a HTML page with the following requirements:

- a fixed header (`headerBox`) and footer (`footerBox`) element (should not scroll)
- the content area contains a top (width 100%, `contentBoxMap`) element that can be expanned over the whole content area
- a left (`contentBoxLeft`) and right (`contentBoxRight`) content element beneath the top content element (`contentBoxMap`)
- the right content element (`contentBoxRight`) should expand to the bottom and scroll if there is overflow.

I've come up with a [solution](http://jsbin.com/ofuwu3/19) [jsbin] that almost works. The problem there is some overflow in the right content element which flows beneath the footer. See the following picture as an example:
[alt text http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/897/screenshot150206.png](http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/897/screenshot150206.png)

**Question:**

1. Can anyone tell me how to fix the overflow problem in `contentBoxRight`? I'm also glad if you could tell me what's the problem with my current solution.
2. Is this even a good approach to do it, considering browser compatibility? Finally, it should look the same on IE 7+, FF 3+, Safari 3+. IE6 and Opera should look ok, but it doesn't matter if it differs abit.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Why don’t you just use `position: fixed` for the content area(s) as well?

Comment: @igor: there is no `position: fixed`, just `absolute`. The reason was to make it also work on IE6, but that was just the initial idea. I have yet to test it on IE6.

Comment: .. Yes there is a `position: fixed;`! http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: @Hristo, I meant there is no `position: fixed` div in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the property `height:100%;` in `#contentBoxRight` and then fix the blue background of `#contentBox`.